# Why are my clipped images not appearing in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This is my first time using GEE, and I'm still a bit of a beginner at JavaScript.

I'm using the NAIP dataset, and I'm trying to show two clipped images, one from 2012 and one from 2020 (the dataset goes back to 2002 so this isn't the issue). My code is creating layers, but not the images connected with them. My geometry variable (polygon import over lower Manhattan) has also been defined, so I don't think that is the issue either. I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with my code; it's pasted below:

```
var yearBefore = '2012'
var yearAfter = '2020'

var datasetBefore = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(yearBefore +'-01-01', yearBefore + '-12-31'))

var datasetAfter = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(yearAfter +'-01-01', yearAfter +'-12-31'))
                  
var befImg = datasetBefore.select(['R', 'G', 'B'])
befImg = befImg.median().clip(geometry);

var aftImg = datasetAfter.select(['R', 'G', 'B'])
aftImg = aftImg.median().clip(geometry);

var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 255,
};

Map.setCenter(-73.998, 40.7309, 13); 
Map.addLayer(aftImg, trueColorVis, yearAfter);
Map.addLayer(befImg, trueColorVis, yearBefore);
```

I've been able to clip and show one image before successfully, so I think the problem lies in that I'm trying to do multiple.

Answer (score 0):

> (the dataset goes back to 2002 so this isn't the issue)

This is the issue. NAIP isn't collected in every state in every year. NAIP data for New York is only available in 2006, 2009, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019, 2021, and 2022. You'll need to change your date filters to match those years.

It's always good practice to check the size of a collection after filtering to make sure there are images that match your criteria.

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel a bit silly about that, but I guess the best way to learn is to make mistakes! Will make sure to double-check the size of collections from now on.